# Unidentified reference error during compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors

I am writing a program that implements a doubly-linked list. My problem is that when I compile if by issuing the command

```
g++ -g -Wall DynamicSequenceVector.cpp DynamicSequenceVector.h main.cpp
```

I receive the following console output

```
/tmp/cc6P5VZK.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `DynamicNode::DynamicSequenceVector<int>::DynamicSequenceVector(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `DynamicNode::DynamicSequenceVector<int>::~DynamicSequenceVector()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `DynamicNode::DynamicSequenceVector<int>::~DynamicSequenceVector()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have a feeling this is a problem with how I am importing the files in main.cpp, because if I move the main function into the DyanmicSequenceVector.cpp file, it compiles perfectly fine. In addition, I only receive these compilation errors when I construct a new object with a parameter.

DynamicSequenceVector.h

```
#ifndef __DYNAMIC_VECTOR
#define __DYNAMIC_VECTOR

namespace DynamicNode {

template <class Type>
class DynamicSequenceVector {
    private:
        struct dynamicNode {
            dynamicNode *previousLink;
            dynamicNode *nextLink;
            Type data;
            int position;
        };

        int nodeCount;
        int currentPosition;
        dynamicNode *headNode;
        dynamicNode *tailNode;
        dynamicNode *currentNode;
        dynamicNode *tempNode;

    public:
        DynamicSequenceVector();
        DynamicSequenceVector(Type data);
        ~DynamicSequenceVector();
        void appendNode(Type nodeData);
        void accessData(int startingPosition, int endingPosition);
};

}
#endif
```

DynamicSequenceVector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DynamicSequenceVector.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace DynamicNode;

template <typename Type>
DynamicSequenceVector<Type>::DynamicSequenceVector() {
    nodeCount       = 0;
    currentPosition = NULL;
    headNode        = NULL;
    tailNode        = NULL;
    currentNode     = NULL;
}

template <typename Type>
DynamicSequenceVector<Type>::DynamicSequenceVector(Type nodeData) {
    nodeCount              = 1;
    currentPosition        = 0;
    headNode               = new dynamicNode;
    headNode->previousLink = NULL;
    headNode->nextLink     = NULL;
    headNode->data         = nodeData;
    headNode->position     = 0;
    currentNode            = 
}

template <typename Type>
DynamicSequenceVector<Type>::~DynamicSequenceVector() {
    while(nodeCount != 0) {
        tempNode = tailNode->previousLink;
        delete tailNode;
        tailNode = tempNode;
    }
    return;
}

template <typename Type>
void DynamicSequenceVector<Type>::appendNode(Type nodeData) {
    if (currentPosition == 0) {
        headNode               = new dynamicNode;
        headNode->data         = nodeData;
        headNode->position     = 0;
        headNode->previousLink = NULL;
        headNode->nextLink     = NULL;
    } else {
        tempNode               = new dynamicNode;
        tempNode->data         = nodeData;
        tempNode->previousLink = tailNode;
        tempNode->position     = nodeCount + 1;
        tailNode->nextLink     = tempNode;
        tailNode               = tempNode;
    }

    nodeCount++;
}

template <typename Type>
void DynamicSequenceVector<Type>::accessData(int startingPosition, 
        int endingPosition) {
    cout << "Data accessed";
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DynamicSequenceVector.h"

//using namespace std;
using namespace DynamicNode;

int main() {
    DynamicSequenceVector<int> test();
    DynamicSequenceVector<int> testingVector(5); // gives an error
    //test = new DynamicSequenceVector<char>::DynamicSequenceVector();

    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Comment: Move your template function definitions to the header.

Comment: You cannot put the definition of member functions of a class template in `.cpp` files. Move them into the header

Comment: @AndyProwl Well, if you manually instantiate the template then yes, you can... but that's more work.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, that's the whole story, but I believe in the OP's case the short story was enough ;) But yes, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of the template members must be in the header, not in a separate .cpp file.

When compiling main.cpp, the compiler *needs* the implementation to be visible in order to instantiate `DynamicSequenceVector<int>`, and those are not available.  So the compiler assumes that the template instantiation is available in another compilation unit, but it's not, and that's why the linker fails.

(The DynamicSequenceVector.cpp file doesn't even do anything useful here -- uninstantiated template members are never actually written out in an object file, since that wouldn't make any sense.  Moving the contents into the header file and then deleting the .cpp file is the correct way to resolve this problem.)

---

Alternatively, you can add this to the bottom of DynamicSequenceVector.cpp:

```
template class DynamicSequenceVector<int>;
```

This will instruct the compiler to instantiate this version of the template class and make it available in and exported from that compilation unit.  Then when the linker goes to resolve the symbols in main's compilation unit, it will be able to find them.

However, this would mean that you would need to maintain a centralized list of *every instantiation of this template class*.  That is a lot of work, and is usually considered a bad idea.

Comment: If I put an include statement for the cpp file in the main file, it seems to compile. Thanks.

Comment: @user1876508 Yes, but including a source file is ***wrong***.  Don't do that.  Put the implementation in the header, where it belongs, and throw away the source file.  You don't need it.

Comment: @user1876508 at the very least, rename the cpp file to `DynamicSequenceVectorInlines.h` and include it at the bottom of `DynamicSequenceVector.h`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use templated code implementation in the cpp since the main only knows the h file.. you should move the templated implementation to the h files